# Postman - How can I pass array as variable

Tags: postman

Is there the possibility to use an array variable inside postman?

e.g. inside the body of a request:

```
{
    "myData" : {{arrayVariable}}
}
```

and inside the data file:

```
{
    "arrayVariable": ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Comment: I had a slightly related issue, of trying to pass a array from a pre request script via pm.variables.set. I solved it by doing `JSON.stringify` on the array, seems to work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479494/postman-can-i-save-json-objects-to-environment-variable-so-as-to-chain-it-for-a)

Answer (score 11):

It's possible, you can even add your own keys

[image]

Answer (score 6):

using `variable` with a same name will give you an array

[image]

Comment: it' doesn't seems to work, it complains: "variable will be overwritten by a duplicate key"...

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson It worked, may be they have updated the structure to create an array. If you find the way please let us know.

Comment: The new way of storing is values separated by commas without brackets or quotes
- value1,value2,value3

Answer (score 5):

You can create a JSON body like this:

```
{
    "myData" : [
        {{arrayVariable}}
    ]
}
```

And the variable like this:

```
arrayVariable: "1", "2", "3"
```

where `arrayVariable` is the key and `"1", "2", "3"` is the value.

Answer (score 3):

Postman environment variables are meant to just save data as **string**, so here you are the workaround to pass **array** as environment variable/data file to Postman as a string like this:

```
{
    "arrayVariable": '["1", "2", "3"]'
}
```

Then, add the following piece of code to parse this variable in `pre-request script` in Postman like this:

```
var x = JSON.parse(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("arrayVariable"));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("arrayVariable", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please create your body request like below

```
{
    "myData" : ["{{arrayVariable}}"]
}
```

and there is no change required for data file.you can use as it is.

```
 {
        "arrayVariable": ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
```

It will work definatly.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution worked for me was something like the answer [MickJagger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148686/11216478) provided, but I think it needs some clarifications.
The JSON data file should be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "anArray": "1, \"2\", 3.0, \"Foo\", false"
    }
]
```

which it's value is a string, escaping the quotations for string elements.
(Note that this example differs from example provided by original question, to cover more use cases.)

The variables is as MickJagger said:

```
{
    "value": [{{anArray}}]
}
```

Maybe other solutions works on previous postman versions, but this solution is tested on postman's latest version (by the time of publishing this answer), i.e. v7.34.0 .